# Getting name of key with value null

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, key

I am running a loop through my array to check if `calendar` and `tpoint` have values. In my `else` statement of my `if-statement` I am attempting to get the `key`'s name with `var notSelected = (obj.prop.subProp).val() !== '';`.

I know I am off with my method.. I am just unsure how to get the key name.

So, with my example, since the values in `tpoint` are empty, I am wanting the `var notSelected` to equal `tpoint`.

Anyone know how I can do this?

```
var packageContents = {
    'packages': [
        {
            'price': '23',
            'name': 'Bronze Bundle Package',
            'calendar': {
                'type': '2year',
                'color': 'Brushed Nickel',
            },
            'tpoint': {
                'type': '',
                'touches': '',
                'years': '',
            }
        }
    ]
};

var bundleSet = null;

var bundleSet = null;
packageContents.packages.forEach(function (obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (prop === 'calendar' || prop === 'tpoint') {
            for (var subProp in obj[prop]) {
                if (obj[prop][subProp] !== '') {
                    bundleSet = true;
                } else {
                    bundleSet = false;
                    var notSelected = (obj.prop.subProp).val() !== '';
                    console.log(notSelected);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    console.log(bundleSet);
});
```

Comment: The line that references `obj.prop.subprop` is wrong; it should be `obj[prop][subprop]` as in the `if` statement. Also the call to `.val()` makes no sense; all you need is `obj[prop][subprop]` and that will resolve to the value of the "type", "touches", or "years" property of the "tpoint" object.

Comment: @Pointy I've tried doing something comparable... `var notSelected = (obj[prop][subProp]).val() !== '';`

Comment: you should be seeing an error about that `.val()` reference.

Comment: @Pointy Right, I get `.val` is not a function. I am just unsure how to structure it.

Comment: Just get rid of the `.val()` as it makes no sense. `obj[prop][subprop]` is the expression that resolves to the value of the sub-property. Your code already uses it! Anyway it's really not clear why you're bothering to check it *again* after you've already determined that the sub-property value **is** `''`.

Comment: @Pointy It just reads false if I do that.

Comment: Do you want to just `console.log()` the values of `prop` and `subprop` maybe?

Comment: @Pointy I am wanting the prop value for which its values are empty. In my example's case it would be `tpoint`.

Comment: Well then the string `"tpoint"` is the value of the variable `prop`, so `console.log(prop)` would log the string `"tpoint"`

Comment: @Pointy I completely looked over that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
function hasEmptyProps(prop) {
  return Object.values(prop).some(x => x === '');
}

const result = packageContents.packages.map(x => {
  if (hasEmptyProps(x.calendar)) {
    return 'calendar';
  } else if (hasEmptyProps(x.tpoint)) {
    return 'tpoint'
  } else {
    return '';
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Would return `["tpoint"]` (or an array of "calendar", "", or "tpoint")